# How to pass node v8 args and script args to pm2?

Tags: node.js, production, pm2

I need to be able to start the app below with pm2 but don't know how to start it with pm2.

```
node --expose-gc bin/www arg1 arg2 arg3
```

I know about `--node-args` but I think is only for --expose-gc.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After some digging, I've found out that what I was looking for was the double dash on linux.

The normal code,

```
node --expose-gc bin/www arg1 arg2 arg3
```

The same code using pm2

```
pm2 start bin/www --node-args="--expose-gc" -- arg1 arg2 arg3
```

All v8 arguments you have to put inside `--node-args` and all scrips args to be grabbed from `process.argv` you have to put after the double dash.

I hope that in the future they implement something link --script-args="arg1 arg2 arg3". Would be very nice for those that isn't a linux expert.

Answer (score 21):

Another way is to create application declaration json file where you specify `args` key. Look at [documentation](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/) on PM2 site.

Example of `pm2.json` file:

```
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"        : "appname",
    "script"      : "app.js",
    "args"        : ["-s", "123"],
    "node_args"   : "--harmony",
    "merge_logs"  : true,
    "cwd"         : "/this/is/a/path/to/start/script",
    "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "production"
    }
  }]
}
```

And run it as follows:

```
$ pm2 start pm2.json
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add any custom arguments after `-x --`,

> `pm2 start app.js -x -- --prod`

and node argument as `--node-args="--harmony"`

> `pm2 start app.js --node-args="--harmony"`

**Both**

> `pm2 start app.js --node-args="--harmony" -x -- --prod`

Comment: For sailsJS, refer my this ans for more specific: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32282896/2837412

Answer (score 1):

I had to expose-gc in my pm2 process.js so I had the do the following:

```
{
  "apps" : [
    {
      "name"        : "app",
      "script"      : "bin/www",
      "instances"   : 2,
      "exec_mode"   : "cluster",
      "watch"       : false,
      "node_args"   : "--expose-gc",
      "env"         : {"NODE_ENV": "development"}
    }
  ]
}
```