# using pm2 with environment variables

Tags: npm, environment-variables, pm2

I have the following in my package.json, and it works well. how do i use pm2 with it? i am struggling with setting the env vars

```
ORG=org1 PORT=3333 node ./bin/www
```

the following didnt work:

```
pm2 start -f --attach ORG=org1 PORT=3333 ./bin/www --watch
```

Comment: have you seen this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28980307/how-to-pass-arguments-to-app-using-pm2#32282896