# Could not correctly pass argument to nodejs using pm2

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I used to start a nodejs script with this command

```
node cli/myscript.js -c configs/some-config.json
```

I tried to start the same script using pm2. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28980307/how-to-pass-arguments-to-app-using-pm2) a post handling the same theme.

I tried this :

```
pm2 start cli/myscript.js --node-args="-c configs/some-config.json"
```

I get a syntax error on the config file which I don't get when I don't use pm2.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
0|myscript  |     at checkScriptSyntax
```

I also tried this and get the same error:

```
pm2 start cli/myscript.js -- -c configs/some-config.json
```

It seems like that pm2 tries to execute the config as a js file.. because the config file is a valid json.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the file name in the same-config.json.

```
  {
  "apps" : [{
    "name"        : "myscript",
    "script"      : "cli/myscript.js",
    "watch"       : true,
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "development"
    }
  }]
}
```

Then you can run the node server by following command -

`pm2 start same-config.json`

For more details please refer [PM2 docs](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/)