# I want to know how to use ngrok in PM2

Tags: node.js, pm2, ngrok

pm2 start ngrok http 5000
This is the command I've entered.
But it didn't work out as I wanted.

Please help me to use ngrok using PM2.

If you use ngrk http 5000, you will be able to use it until the terminal is closed.
It works normally.

I want to use this in PM2.

My operating system is Window10 Node-Js.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

download / extract to same folder

https://ngrok.com/download

then run following

```
pm2 start pm2-ngrok.yaml
```

pm2-ngrok.yaml

```
    apps:
      - name : 'ngrok'
        script: './ngrok'
        args: 'http --hostname=YOURSUBDOMAINHERE.ngrok.io PORTHERE'
        instances: '1'
        autorestart: true
        max_restarts: 10
        max_memory_restart: '500M'
        watch : false
        error_file: 'err-prod.log'
        out_file: 'out-prod.log'
        log_file: 'combined-prod.log'
```

run

```
pm2 startup 
pm2 save
```

to persist across reboots

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use -- to pass arguments to ngrok when you run it with pm2:

```
pm2 start ngrok -- http 5000
```

Related question: [How to pass arguments to app using pm2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28980307/how-to-pass-arguments-to-app-using-pm2)

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr4CT.png


but ngrok stoped  ;.;  pls help me

i am  webpage source  => C:\

ngrok install -g

Answer (score 0):

So, first install Ngrok with NPM `npm install ngrok -g`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrok

Then configure your Ngrok.yml acordingly.

After that, you can run your pm2 like in this example.

```
pm2 start npm --name app -- run develop 
pm2 start npm --name ngrok -- run ngrok --all
pm2 monit
```

So `pm2 start npm --name ngrok -- run ngrok --all` runes, the yml configuration for all.

[image]