# How to add arguments to pm2 file execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, pm2

I'm trying to run the cluster.js file on pm2.
When the file is executed locally because two arguments 0 1 are appended after I run it with the 'node cluster.js 0 1' command, and even if I use the node-args command in pm2, I get at least an error with the 'pm2 start "cluster.js 0 1"' command and no arguments are applied. What should I do?

- I'm Korean, and I wrote it through Google Translate, so the translation may be wrong.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28980307/how-to-pass-execution-arguments-to-app-using-pm2. Should be `pm2 start cluster.js --node-args="0 1"`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass node arguments from CLI then

```
pm2 start myServer.js --node-args="--production --port=1337"
```

You also can add any arguments after --

```
pm2 start app.js -- --prod --second-arg --third-arg
```